# 404 error page is allowing access to my database

Tags: php, laravel, xampp

I'm new to programming and I'm developing an online application using Laravel, with XAMPP (on Windows) to host the database. Now when I test the login page I have noticed that when someone types a wrong URL

```
Example: localhost/mysitename/home/wrong name
```

it is displaying a 404 error page with a "go home" button at the bottom which can direct anyone to the database through phpMyAdmin.

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

For starters, restrict your phpMyadmin to only the local host or an IP address on your local network. Find the conf file and make the following changes. Adjust the IP to something that you know.

`/etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf`

`<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin>
Add the following lines at the top:
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from All
Allow from 127.0.0.1`

Next - You really need to look into how to correctly configure Apache and other web services before exposing your front-end.